# Ansible command module expecting nonzero result

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use the Ansible `command` module to get information from my inventory, but I am expecting the servers to return a non-zero value as a result. The non-zero values are causing the inventory to report as fail.

I was expecting the following sequence to fail when a certain group of process names are present on any of the inventory.

```
- name: Make sure all expected processes are down
  tags: ensure_processes_down
  block:
    - name: Find list of unexpected processes
      command:
        argv:
          - /usr/bin/pgrep
          - --list-name
          - unexpected_processes_pattern_here
      register: pgrep_status

    - name: Ensure no processes were found
      # pgrep returns 0 if matches were found
      assert:
        that: pgrep_status.rc != 0
        msg: 'Cannot run while these these processes are up: {{ pgrep_status.stdout }}'
```

I am new to Ansible and suspect that I am not using the `command` module correctly.

Is there another way to run a `command` where the expected return code is non-zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command in a `command` task fails, then the entire task fails, which means no more tasks will be executed on that particular host. Your second task in which you check `pgrep_status` will never run. You have a couple options here.

You can set `ignore_errors: true`, which will ignore the error condition and move on to the next task. E.g:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - command:
        argv:
          - false
      register: status
      ignore_errors: true

    - assert:
        that: status.rc != 0
```

Which will produce this result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "False", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'False'", "rc": 2, "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring

TASK [assert] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

However, rather than running the `command` task and then checking the result in a second task, you can set a `failed_when` condition on the command task:

```
    - name: Find list of unexpected processes
      command:
        argv:
          - /usr/bin/pgrep
          - --list-name
          - unexpected_processes_pattern_here
      register: pgrep_status
      failed_when: pgrep_status.rc == 0
```

This command will only fail when the command returns successfully (i.e.,with an exit code of `0`).

See the "[Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure)" section of the docs for more information.